# MySQL JDBC error on connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to establish a connection to remote mysql db. I have put the jar connector to`war/WEB-INF/lib` folder and added a library (build path).

Still I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sql4.freemysqlhosting.net
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the full code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.infograph.dbconnection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * @author Vlad
 *
 */
public class DBConnection 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    public DBConnection() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;

        try 
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sql4.freemysqlhosting.net","user", "pass");

        } 
        catch (SQLException e1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) 
        {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem?? 10x!

Comment: What is `sql4.freemysqlhosting.net`?

Comment: it is the host of the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you meant to use is

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql4.freemysqlhosting.net","user", "pass");
```

You possibly need to add a port number and schema name.

The URL you provided, `jdbc:sql4.freemysqlhosting.net`, is not valid, or at least it doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection url must be in form jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/schema in order for DriverManager to determine which driver to use.
Here's more on this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html